# Using struct update syntax to init struct passing fields of another struct

Tags: rust

```rust
struct A
{
  field1 : i32,
  field2 : i32
}

impl Default for A
{
  fn default() -> Self
  {
      Self
      {
        field1 : 0,
        field2 : 1
      }
  }
}

struct B
{
  field2 : i32
}

fn main()
{
  let b = B{ field2 : 2 };
  let a = A 
  { 
    field2 : b.field2,
    .. Default::default()
  };
}
```

Is there an expression that allows to pass fields of `b` into initialization of struct `A` without explicitly typing field names in case when both structs have common properties of the same type?

Like use:

```rust
let a = A 
{ 
  ..b,
  .. Default::default()
};
```

Instead of:

```rust
let a = A 
{ 
  field2 : b.field2,
  .. Default::default()
};
```

Comment: There's no such thing yet. But, you could make a macro.